# Huge blend file, extreme lag when parenting certain object and moving in pose mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, armature, pose-mode

So basically Im trying to rig my character. And whenever I parent these shoes with automatic weights it causes extreme lag on pose mod. Even when I turn off the subdivision modifier it still lags, not just when moving the feet bones but when I move the armature in general.

I noticed my blend file is a huge size, would this be due to the textures on the shoes? I removed as many materials and objects as possible but it still lags when posing.

Blend file is too big to upload so will attach google drive link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HuKYQf1dNHKij-sK5ik0zjG6MNbTvmjm/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1.3Gb does seem excessively large for a simple character like that. Have you got any orphan data? In the outliner, click display mode at the top and choose `orphan data` then hit `purge`

Comment: Only the brushes deleted all the materials already

Comment: Also, removing textures from an object does not remove it from your file, you need to do the `purge` method above, or save, close and reopen your file. Any unused data will be removed when closing the file

Comment: Ok I think i found the issue i just unhid all my duplicates and the old shoes with an insane vertices count showed up so it was most likely those

Comment: Ok... You've got several objects in there with millions of verts each! I deleted the copies of the shoes that looked like they'd had sub-d modifiers applied and the file size dropped to 2.9Mb... Yes, MB!!!! Also, many of your objects have sub-d levels of 6 for the viewport, 2 is usually more than enough for visualization. Dial them back and you'll find things run a whole lot smoother!

Comment: Lol... I didn't see your comment! Yeah man, you're on it!

Comment: Hahah thank you so much